# in emacs-lisp, how to position point in middle of text string?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

In emacs-lisp, how do I position the point in the middle of a text string? I'd like my cursor to wind up where the `%s` is in the following function:

```
(defun web-research ()
(interactive)
(insert "#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n\n%s\n#+END_QUOTE\n")
(org-mac-chrome-insert-frontmost-url)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options.
E.g.,

```
(defun web-research ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n\n%s\n#+END_QUOTE\n")
  (search-backward "%")
  (org-mac-chrome-insert-frontmost-url))
```

or

```
(defun web-research ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n\n")
  (let ((p (point)))
    (insert "\n\n#+END_QUOTE\n")
    (org-mac-chrome-insert-frontmost-url)
    (goto-char p))
```

or

```
(defun web-research ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n\n%s")
  (save-excursion (insert "\n#+END_QUOTE\n"))
  (org-mac-chrome-insert-frontmost-url))
```

IMO the second is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like [yasnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) for this.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: web-research
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
# key: wr
# --
#+BEGIN_QUOTE

%s$0

#+END_QUOTE
`(if (boundp 'org-mac-chrome-get-frontmost-url) (org-mac-chrome-get-frontmost-url) "http://www.example.com/")`
```

I don't seem to have `org-mac-chrome-get-frontmost-url` or the `insert` variant, but after a quick search, I'm guessing `org-mac-chrome-get-frontmost-url` is the thing to use with this solution.